# Crimson Altars wont spawn in terraria

Tags: terraria

I have the crimson (NOT corruption), killed the WoF, but i only get Demon Altars. They have the graphics of Crimson Altars, but when i mouse over them it says: Demon Altar. I've destroyed a bunch of these crimson looking Demon Altars and all i get is Palladium / Adamantite / Orichalum. Why wont the titanium spawn?

Comment: ok, so i need to keep breaking altars and hope it will eventually pop some titanium. thx

Comment: I believe that any single world will only get one of the ores from each tier. Breaking more altars will continue to give you Adamantite instead of Titanium.

Answer (score 14):

The tool-tip for Crimson Altars *is* Demon Altar. This is a bug in the game. Both Demon Altars and Crimson Altars can spawn the alternative ores. The one you get is random and not linked to the crimson/corruption of the world. Your world gets one ore from each tier by random.

```
Hardmode Tier 1 | Cobalt      OR  Palladium
Hardmode Tier 2 | Mythril     OR  Orichalcum
Hardmode Tier 3 | Adamantite  OR  Titanium
```

Comment: Note you have to create a new world and see if destroying altars there will spawn different ores.

Comment: If you quit without saving after breaking the 1st, 2nd or 3rd altar, you can re-roll whether the old or new ore type spawns.

Comment: @kotekzot: Interesting, if true.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you wont get Titanium is that it is a 50/50 chance to get cobalt/pallidium, orichalum or mythril, and adamantite or titanium, you got adamantite, but getting demon alters instead of crimson doesn't matter, its just a bug.